# UITabBarItem without UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, action, tabbar

how implement a UITabBarItem in a UITableViewController?

how do I implement the action (click) of a TabBar item - Favourites with a method?

this is my tableviewcontroller.h

```
@interface bibliotecaViewFinale : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *myTabBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic)Aule_Biblioteche *aulebib;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label_info;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *infobib;
@end
```

What should I write in .m?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but if you need table view (controller) inside tab bar controller, you should use default or write custom tab bar controller and put tvc as a child.

If you need just a button that looks like tab bar item, still you should write a custom view with table view as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thought ,make one of the tabbaritems acts like UIButton,while others act as normal.Here is my code:

```
@interface myTabBarVC()<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation myTabBarVC
-(void)viewDidLoad{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   self.delegate=self;
}
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
NSInteger itemindex =    [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
if (itemindex == 0) {//change 0 to any tabbaritem's index your want to change
    //add action here
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
@end
```

The only problem is this tabbaritem acts like unbutton,it's color won't change  when you select it.I can't figure to fix it.